# Jmeter: Failing to execute next component after while controller(using CSV data config also)

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter test plan with while controller, which loops over URLs from a CSV(CSV contains only URLs):

[image]

However the next component 'HTTP Request' never gets executed. in log viewer, I can see this:

> 2021-02-24 20:23:29,317 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stop Thread seen
> for thread Thread Group 1-1, reason:
> org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of
> file:C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/jmeter/urls.csv detected for
> CSVDataSet:CSV Data Set Config configured with stopThread:true,
> recycle:false

If I set stopThread to False, then this controller never stops. Is there any solution to this?

While controller is configured as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set both "Recycle on EOF" and "Stop thread on EOF" to false because:

- if you will be recycling on EOF - the while controller will never stop
- if you stop thread on EOF - no elements after the While Controller will be executed

So

1. Configure your CSV Data Set Config like:

   [image]
2. Put your "OWA Inbox Access" sampler under the [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and use the following __jexl3() function as the condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${myVar}" != "<EOF>",)}
   ```

More information: [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter), see **Reading all Values from the CSV and Continue** chapter

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. But as I read your article on given link, I am able to achieve upto: where we get last <EOF> with the condition `${__javaScript("${path}" != "<EOF>",)}` in `while`  controller. But when I give condition`"${path}" != "<EOF>"` in `IF` controller, the whole while loop does not get executed.